# How to modify big JSON file

Tags: json, go

I have a large json file with multiple levels of nesting. Now I need to modify the value of each key in this file with the Go code. I know of two methods: **the first** is to obtain each key and then modify its value, but there is no doubt that this method is too complicated and prone to errors. **The second** method is to serialize the entire json file into a struct, then modify the struct field, and then deserialize it. However, this case needs to define a struct of several hundred lines, which is also very complicated.

Is there any other way?

for example my json is like this, but more bigger, 100+ lines :

```
{
    "user": [{
        "cdb_id":"",
        "firstname":"Tom",
        "lastname":"Bradley",
        "phone":14155555555,
        "email":"tom@gmail.com",
        "address":[{
            "street":"4343 shoemaker ave",
            "city":"Brea",
            "zip":"92821",
            "country":"USA"
        }],
        "authenticators":[{
            "name":"Lisa Hayden",
            "phone":15625555555
        },{
            "name":"Pavan M",
            "phone":17145555555
        }],
        "voice_sig":"242y5-4546-555kk54-437879ek545",
        "voicesig_created_time":"2017-08-02T21:27:44+0000",
        "status":"verified"
    }]
}
```

I need modify "cdb_id"/"lastname"/"street"/"phone"/ "voice_sig".....all these keys' value, Except make a struct or get the keys' value one by one and modify, do i have any other way?

**The new values for those keys will be POST request from Web Pages.**

Comment: You could unmarshal into a `map[string]interface{}` but you'll have to do a lot of type assertion and errror checking. Also just a quick heads-up, you have serialize & deserialize backward - you serialize an in-memory value into an encoded format (e.g. JSON), and deserialize an encoded format into an in-memory value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json pointer:

https://godoc.org/github.com/go-openapi/jsonpointer

Or, you can read it in a map[string]interface{} and work your way through, but that gets tedious.

Answer (score 0):

Now my way is use this website, switch my Json to struct, and modify one by one. But it just think this is not so good way, so i am eagering for a better way.
http://json2struct.mervine.net/

```
type MyJsonName struct {
    User []struct {
        Address []struct {
            City    string `json:"city"`
            Country string `json:"country"`
            Street  string `json:"street"`
            Zip     string `json:"zip"`
        } `json:"address"`
        Authenticators []struct {
            Name  string `json:"name"`
            Phone int    `json:"phone"`
        } `json:"authenticators"`
        CdbID               string `json:"cdb_id"`
        Email               string `json:"email"`
        Firstname           string `json:"firstname"`
        Lastname            string `json:"lastname"`
        Phone               int    `json:"phone"`
        Status              string `json:"status"`
        VoiceSig            string `json:"voice_sig"`
        VoicesigCreatedTime string `json:"voicesig_created_time"`
    } `json:"user"`
}
```

Comment: I would say that this is the correct way to do this. The only suggestion that I would have is to break this into smaller pieces that can make more sense within your application. this way once this data is "deserialized" you can use the structs to manipulate this data and then "serialize" it back should it be needed. Usually when I do this kind of thing I create an interface to my main application and then use these serializers to feed data into the application in an abstract manner  that allows me to throw away the serializer should the data format change.

Comment: Thank u so much, If that, i will walk on this way.